# Can I configure kafka so that consumers use one network interface and cluster replication uses another?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Is there a way to configure kafka such that replication traffic occurs on one network and consumers connect via another network. It seems from the documentation that both brokers and consumers will use the `advertised.listeners` parameter. I'd like to separate this traffic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can configure Kafka to use different network interfaces for user and replication traffic.

First, let's define some nice names for our interfaces. For example, a `USERS` interface for external traffic using `SASL_SSL` and another interface `REPLICATION` with only `SSL` for replication (you can map any protocols you want to the names, `SASL_SSL` and `SSL` are just examples):

```
listener.security.protocol.map=USERS:SASL_SSL,REPLICATION:SSL
```

Then define the listeners:

```
listeners=USERS://:9092,REPLICATION://:9093
advertised.listeners=USERS://some-network:9092,REPLICATION://another-network:9093
```

Finally set the inter broker protocol:

```
inter.broker.listener.name=REPLICATION
```

In this example, you would then give your users `some-network:9092` as the bootstrap address.

Take the time to read the docs about each of these settings: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs

Comment: I was wondering what would be the use case or advantage of using different interface for replication .. if you have some idea ,please throw some light !

Comment: You can do that for performance so replication does not affect user traffic, especially when using `replication.factor=3`. Also that allows to fully separate external and internal traffic and each interface can have a different security protocol.